# What counts as channeled energy for this tiefling ability?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic, healing

I have a character with variant [tiefling](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-tiefling/) ability #49:

> You are healed by both positive and negative channeled energy.

Several spells state that *You channel positive energy* or *If you are healed by negative energy then this spell heals you.*

How do the following spells and special abilities affect this tiefling? What heals him and what harms him?

- [*inflict wounds*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/inflict-light-wounds/)
- [*chill touch*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/chill-touch/)
- [*harm*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/harm/)
- [*repair undead*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/repair-undead/)
- [channel energy](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/#Channel_Energy_Su) when used to harm living creatures
- [channel energy](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/#Channel_Energy_Su) when used to heal undead creatures

Does having one or more [necrografts](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/necrograft/) affect this in any way besides dulling the effects of positive energy?

Comment: I removed it entirely since all of it sounded like narrative fluff which wouldn't impact the rules whatsoever hence being opinion-oriented, but if I was mistaken and you feel there's some aspect of the description you gave that would actually have rules implications -- affecting the actual objective rules, not "what's your opinion on this?" -- state something like "My tiefling is also XYZ. Does that affect the ruling?" (e.g. "my tiefling has necrografts")

Comment: @doppelgreener can you please explain how i can include some of what you cut in my question as that would drastically change how some gms would rule those spells (since undead heal from all negative energy unless otherwise stated, and i have undead parts) and i still wanted some of that information.

Comment: If you're investigating the rules, stick to what would reflect changes to actual rules. "My character straddles life and death" is narrative fluff, for example, and how someone would rule spells affecting that is wholly opinion. "My character has necrografts" might affect things? I'm not sure. Our guideline here is: "I want you to explain how X works to me" is good, "tell me what your completely arbitrary personal opinion on X would be" is not good. (see [questions to avoid asking](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask))

Comment: After it was pointed out in my now-deleted answer, I really do think the word *channeled* needs to be emphasized somewhere in this question. Seriously, isn't the real rules question here *What counts as channeled energy for this special ability?*

Comment: Actually, Necrografts would not affect any of this in any way...they simply reduce the amount of magical healing, irregardless of source. Neither Postitive or negative energy, or channeling, would change this behaviour.

Comment: Right, but that seems poorly defined to me... Because if I were a dhampir with necrografts... Why would negative energy heal me any less when both undead, and dhampir heal from negative energy... I guess by 100% RAW it wouldnt.  Ugh. What a can of worms.

Comment: @erudaki You seem to be assuming that Necrografts retard healing due to adding undead parts to a creature...perhaps they actually reduce healing by reducing the structural integrity of the creature, meaning that would quite well explain the reduction in both positive and negative energy healing. Not to mention, there are other magical healing effects that are related to neither positive nor negative energy, such as Infernal or Celestial Healing, or Regenerate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the variant trait is all we have to go on here. I believe the relevant part of the trait is actually the idea that the tiefling is healed by both positive and negative energy - nothing is said about any other effect. And, as you have found, the defintion of Channel is a little rubbery. So, I can only see two ways to treat this.

1. The change is intended to only alter the clerical Channel Energy ability, when it is used to heal. No change is made to the way Channel Energy to harm works (meaning the tiefling would be harmed by a negative Channel to harm, but not a positive Channel to harm), nor is any change made to the way Cure or Inflict spells work (meaning a Cure spell will heal, and an Inflict spell will cause damage). Spells that heal without either type of energy (such as Regenerate, or Celestial or Infernal Healing) are unaffected, as is Natural Healing.
2. The change is intended to change the way a tiefling reacts to all positive and negative energy. The tiefling is healed by any effect that says it heals via positive or negative energy, regardless of whether channeling is mentioned. This would then mean that the tiefling would be healed by both cure and inflict spells.  Spells that heal without either type of energy (such as Regenerate, or Celestial or Infernal Healing) are unaffected, as is Natural Healing.

In the absence of anything definitive, expect table variation, and a final ruling by the individual GM.